Spring Cloud Binder function - acknowledge and throw error
I am wondering how the spring cloud views/would view the requirement of consuming from a cloud binder as a function, transforming that object by getting some data from an api (or something similar) and handling any exceptions coming from that api. Specifically being able to manually acknowledge only certain exceptions (i.e ack every exception BUT rate limit as seen below)
I know we can do this for consumers but what about functions? Would this be possible/advised? Does the ack still function as expected even with an exception thrown?
Locally using Kafka test containers I get the desired result where an offset is incremented only for non rate limit exceptions, but perhaps this is frowned up or there is a better way of approaching this? Essentially I do not want to block the consumer except in exceptional cases where it's obviously not appropriate to carry on consuming. Ive given some sample pseudo code to show you what I mean. Cheers!
@Configuration
public class FunctionConfig {

    private final ApiClient client;

    @Bean
    public Function<Message<EventIn>, Message<EventOut>> someBinderFunction() {
        return message -> {
            EventIn event = message.getPayload();
            Acknowledgment acknowledgment = getAck(message);

            try {
                Response response = client.execute(event.getId());

                EventOutKey key = Mapper.mapKey(response);
                EventOut value = Mapper.toValue(response);
                acknowledgment.acknowledge();
                return MessageBuilder.withPayload(value).setHeader(KafkaHeaders.KEY, key).build();
            } catch (RateLimitException ex) {
                throw ex;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                acknowledgment.acknowledge();
                throw ex;
            }
        };
    }

    private Acknowledgment getAck(Message<EventIn> message) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(message.getHeaders().get(KafkaHeaders.ACKNOWLEDGMENT, Acknowledgment.class))
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("Incoming message had no Acknowledgement header"));
    }
}

spring:
  kafka.bootstrap-servers: ${kafka.settings.bootstrap-servers}
  cloud:
    function.definition: someBinderFunction
    stream:
      default:
        producer.useNativeEncoding: true
        consumer.useNativeEncoding: true
      bindings:
        someBinderFunction-in-0:
          destination: topic-in
          group: group-id
          content-type: application/*+avro
        someBinderFunction-out-0:
          destination: topic-out
          content-type: application/*+avro


First of all, I do not see a configuration where you enable MANUAL ack. You need to enable it by providing the corresponding property.
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.someBinderFunction-in-0.consumer.ack-mode: MANUAL

Only if you provide this property the framework provide you with access to the acknowledgment header and the associated Acknowledgement object.
Now, on to the question you asked. If I understand correctly, you only want to acknowledge records when you get non-rate-limit exceptions. If you get a rate-limit exception, then you don't want any acknowledgment.
First, let us look at the non-rate-limit exception scenario:
catch (Exception ex) {
                acknowledgment.acknowledge();
                throw ex;
            }

You are acknowledging the record here and then re-throwing the exception. The record is already acknowledged, but the function throws an exception, which triggers a retry by the binder. Why are you doing that if the record is already ack'd. You could simply log the exception in the catch block and then call acknowledge(). This way, the framework will not attempt the same record again.
Second, with the rate-limit exception, you rethrow the exception, which triggeres the retry by the binder. Once the retries are exhausted, the record remains unacknowledged and the next record will be delivered. The issue, though, is that, once the new record is acknowledged (assuming no rate-limit occurred this time), the consumer offset is incremented, and the record that was failing from the rate-limit is never redelivered within the same consumer group.
A better solution that you can probably look into is using a DLT (DLQ), in which, any records that throw an exception, is sent to the dead-letter-topic. In that way, you will not lose any messages. Later, another processor can be run against this DLT topic and successfully process the records.
To recap, two things stand out from the code you shared:

Do not re/throw an exception after acknowledging the record. If you do this, then things could get into unpredictable behavior.
By acknowledging in one catch block and not in the other, you increment the offset without fully processing a record. Depending on your use case this may or may not be an issue. If data loss is critical, then the usage of a DLT should be evaluated.

Incidentally, one other thing I noticed.
consumer.useNativeEncoding: true

That should be
consumer.useNativeDecoding: true


Hi thank you for your response! The reason why I re-throw is that the function requires a response of some kind, I can't log and return null I don't think? I do have the ack mode set yes MANUAL_IMMEDIATE I just didn't show it in the sample apologies.

Another note is that I played with the idea of an error handler, getting the failed message from that ErrorMessage and acknowledging there? Then in theory the function just takes a response or an exception but the error consumer can consume and handle the acknowledgement logic?

Logging the error, acknowledging it, and returning null should be fine. The framework will ignore that null value. Keep in mind, though, that the record from the rate-limit exception is potentially lost because any records that are acknowledged in the other catch block will increment the offset. The next consumer poll will never go back to the record that threw the rate-limit exception.
